# making a dataset of multiple x values in one y value

Tags: r, dataset, scatter-plot

I have a correlation dataset that looks like this:

```
V1    V2    R2    
 1    2    0.4    
 1    3    0.5    
 3    5    0.3
```

And i want to convert it to a two-column data in such a way that I would have multiple x (in column V) in one y (in column R2) for scatter plotting. It would look like this:

```
V    R2    
1    0.4    
2    0.4        
1    0.5    
2    0.5    
3    0.5    
3    0.3    
4    0.3    
5    0.3
```

How can I do this in R?

Comment: How are you getting 8 ids in the output from 6 ids in the input?

Comment: for example, first data tells a 0.4 correlation between 1 and 2. I want then to produce two data from that, being (1,0.4) and (2,0.4).

Comment: my x axis in the example runs from 1 to 5.

Comment: oooh... so in the second row 1/3 means 1 to 3, hence why you get 1,2,3 in the output. I'm with you now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the tidyverse, you can make a list column of the required vectors with `purrr::map2` to iterate `seq` over each pair of start and end points, and then expand with `tidyr::unnest`:

```r
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(1L, 1L, 3L), 
                 V2 = c(2L, 3L, 5L), 
                 R2 = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.3))

library(tidyverse)

df %>% transmute(V = map2(V1, V2, seq), R2) %>% unnest()
#>    R2 V
#> 1 0.4 1
#> 2 0.4 2
#> 3 0.5 1
#> 4 0.5 2
#> 5 0.5 3
#> 6 0.3 3
#> 7 0.3 4
#> 8 0.3 5
```

In base R, there isn't a simple equivalent of `unnest`, so it's easier to use `Map` (the multivariate `lapply`, roughly equivalent to `purrr::map2` above) to build a list of data frames, complete with the `R2` value (recycled by `data.frame`), which than then be `do.call(rbind, ...)`ed into a single data frame:

```r
do.call(rbind, 
        Map(function(v1, v2, r2){data.frame(V = v1:v2, R2 = r2)}, 
            df$V1, df$V2, df$R2))
#>   V  R2
#> 1 1 0.4
#> 2 2 0.4
#> 3 1 0.5
#> 4 2 0.5
#> 5 3 0.5
#> 6 3 0.3
#> 7 4 0.3
#> 8 5 0.3
```

Check out the intermediate products of each to get a feel for how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(V = V1:V2, R2), by = .(grp = 1:nrow(df1))][, grp := NULL][]
#   V  R2
#1: 1 0.4
#2: 2 0.4
#3: 1 0.5
#4: 2 0.5
#5: 3 0.5
#6: 3 0.3
#7: 4 0.3
#8: 5 0.3
```